# Searching for leads to the binary codes for specific actions on tv/dvd remotes

Tags: controller, binary, television, infrared

Using Google, I was able to find one site that listed a 7 digit binary code for a Sony tv remote to turn the tv on or off as well as the sequences assigned to specific buttons (without info on what each button was assigned to trigger). Most of the Google searches I did interpreted "code" as referring to the (often four) numbers assigned to specific tv or dvd player and not to the binary code used by the remote to signal specific actions (pause, stop, fast forward, skip to next chapter, etc.). I am aiming at finding more examples that are more complete for at least Sony and Samsung.

Comment: Please consider checking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get better response

Comment: Thank you. I did read through two of the articles; hope this is an improvement, but if not, I can try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the hex values associated to the keys on the remote, then I believe you can get some of them from the remotes configuration files for [lircd](http://www.lirc.org/html/lircd.html), found in the [git repo of the lirc project](https://sourceforge.net/p/lirc-remotes/code/ci/master/tree/remotes/).

For example, the [Sony RM-ED009 remote control conf file](https://sourceforge.net/p/lirc-remotes/code/ci/master/tree/remotes/sony/RM-ED009.lircd.conf) says the button used to turn the volume up produces the value 0x490 on the receiver side.